# Why is Facebook Actions field is returning null value

Tags: facebook-graph-api, report

In our API reports we noticed that we always get the Actions filed with no values.

after checking this with facebook support we understood that our request query was wrong. we are able to get the data with the following query that the suggested to us:

https://graph.facebook.com/act_52081533/adgroupstats?start_time=2013-04-22T00%3A00%3A00+-0700&end_time=2013-04-23T00%3A00%3A00+-0700&include_deleted=true&stats_mode=with_delivery&&limit=500&offset=0&access_token

I'm getting the same data as the UI present on 22/4/2013 but I don't understand why they are including 23/4/2013 date and why they using '+-0700'. The account time zone is GMT -8.

I read all documents referring this issue but could not found an explanation to this patters.

Comment: You've read the notes at the end of the [Ad Statistics](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adstatistics/) documentation, yes? What issue are you having with it? It sounds like you're simply including the wrong offset from GMT for that account

Comment: I can't find an explanation for why to include "+-0700" parameter after the time stamp. this was a solution that was given to me by Facebook but no one returns to me with an explanation ...

Comment: +0700 is only valid for ad accounts with a UTC offset of +7, you need to adjust the timestamps to take the ad account's timezone into account, this is returned to you via the API

Comment: OK, so i think what confuses me that in the "Ad Account Settings" > "Time Zone" - for the specific account is set to be (GMT-08:00) Pacific Time, than why do I get data only when using 7?

Comment: Daylight savings time?